# Cmake Error : referring to old revision even though upgraded to new revision

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, cmake, cross-compiling

```
CMake Error: your C compiler: "/home/user/revision OLD/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc" was not found.   
Please set CMAKE_C_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.

CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "/home/user/revision OLD/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc" was not found.
Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

---

I changed my revision to new even though it refers to revision OLD path. I read on wiki FAQ
they suggested like

```
$ cmake -G "Your Generator" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-4.2 -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.2 path/to/your/source
```

but is the right way to do it ? Because I heard that there are some downside like resets other FLAGS ?

I have no idea about cmake at all.

Comment: Have you tried using `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/home/user/revision\ new/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/home/user/revision\ new/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc" <path>` ?

My guess is that CMake is finding the `OLD` path in the `CC` and `CXX` environment variable, maybe check that as well (`echo $CC`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/new/revision/cc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/new/revision/c++ .` in your build dir. But this will cause CMake to do total reconfiguration, so you will lost your changes to default config.

AFAIK, there is no way to prevent CMake from doing this, because it's done intentionally. CMake sets a lot of internal configuration vars based on selected compiler, and because of that it repeat it when you change the compiler.

The only way to workaround this - make symlink to the compiler of the newer revision.